# Crypt_RSA phpseclib3 PHP 8 Issue

Tags: php, rsa, crypt

As the title says:

We have recently upgraded to PHP 8 however, Crypt/RSA.php is deprecated and will not be supported in PHP 8 anymore, so we are forced to find another solution.

I heard that phpseclib3 is the same and able to support it, however, I cannot get it to work.

This is my current code:

```html
$rsa = \phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA::loadPrivateKey($private_key);
$rsa = $rsa->withHash('sha256'); 
$rsa = $rsa->withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$ans = $rsa->sign("test");
echo $ans;
```

This is the previous code that works:

```html
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey($private_key);

    $rsa->setHash('sha256');     // Specify digest, e.g. sha256 (default is sha1)
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

    $signature = base64_encode($rsa->sign($string_to_encrypt));
```

with the new code, I am getting this error: Uncaught OutOfRangeException: Signature representative out of range in xxx

The Key is the same so definitely, it is not the key's problem, I am unable to figure out what was wrong, can anyone help me with this?

Any help is appreciated!

Test Key:

```html
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Is this line really `$ans = $key->sign("test");` and not for example `$ans = $rsa->sign("test");`?

Comment: Sorry it is $rsa->sign("Test"); got the wrong code, edited!

Comment: The phpseclib v3 code works for me under 8.2.0 without problems. Can you post a test key with which the problem occurs?

Comment: @Topaco I have edited a put on a test key, it is a weird byte, it works on the old code though, but not the new one.

Comment: This is *not* a valid key. You can check this e.g. with OpenSSL (*openssl rsa -in <path to key> -check*) or with an ASN.1 parser like https://lapo.it/asn1js.

Comment: @Topaco that is the problem, because the key is valid on the Crypt/RSA old version, you can test out using the previous code, but never valid on other version anymore..

Comment: The key is not valid in the sense that it does not meet the specification of a PKCS#1 key. That the old phpseclib version allows the key is actually a bug in the old version. The behavior of the new version is correct, which does not allow invalid keys.

Comment: In that case, is there any way to get it to work? Our partner will not probably change the system, and our PHP version is already updated to 8.0, it is going to be a problem for us..

Comment: You can try to fix the invalid key, but in general the fixed key will not produce the same signatures and these signatures will not be verifiable by the other side. Probably you will have to use new (valid) key pairs.

Comment: This will probably not work, as the new key generated still will have the same sign..

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your key generation and it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, can be done via OpenSSL RSA Sign.

Comment: Both, question and answer are unclear, please add more details to the question, not just a link, and more details to the response.